# Declaration cannot be marked 'static', why

Tags: swift, enums

I have a `School` struct:

```
public struct School {
  ...
}
```

Then, I have an extension for it, in which I declare a static enum:

```
extension School {
  // Compiler error: Declaration cannot be marked 'static'
  static enum Level: String {
     case Middle = "middle"
  }
}
```

But I got compiler error as mentioned in comment above, how can I declare a static enum in extension then?

Comment: Please never post sample code that is invalid. There's no such thing as `structure` in Swift, that should be `struct`. And please read the Swift book by Apple. Swift is not Java and this is not your first question, where you assumed something in Swift would work the same way it does in Java, which would become clear as soon as you read that book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `enum` is a type and hence it cannot be marked static. Even if you declare an `enum` inside a class, it will be accessible through the class type and not through an instance. In Swift, the `static` keyword can be used to mark type properties, but since `enum` is a type itself, it cannot be a property and hence cannot be marked `static`.

```
struct School {

}

extension School {
    enum Level: String {
        case Middle = "middle"
    }
}
```

You can access the `enum` through the `School` type, you don't need to create an instance.

```
School.Level.Middle
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Only properties and methods of a type can be marked static. If you have a class that has a static method or property and require it to be subclassed it should be marked class and not static. Just a little addition to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Only properties and methods of a type can be marked static. (Enum is a value type like struct) In addition if you have a class that has a static method or property and require it to be subclassed it should be marked class and not static.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, inner types have access to the members of the enclosing type. The `static` keyword is used to block such access and to indicate that the type is independent of the members of its enclosing type.

Swift doesn't do that from the start, so it doesn't have a use for `static` inner types.